# Is it possible to unit discrete region and use RegionDifference to subtract it?

Tags: regions

I am testing my idea to find the difference between two regions, while one region has discrete sub-regions. I find that RegionUnion and RegionDifference have problems dealing with such problems. 
I post my script here for a quick check

```
 `d1 = Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.4];
  d2 = Disk[{1.5, 1.5}, 0.4];
  d3 = Disk[{1.5, 0.5}, 0.4];
  d4 = Disk[{0.5, 1.5}, 0.4];
  u1 = Region[RegionUnion[d1, d2, d3, d4], Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
  RegionDimension[u1]
   Area[u1]
  u2 = Region[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}], Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
  RegionDimension[u2]
  D1 = Region[RegionDifference[u2, u1], Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I hope to get the region without those four disks in the rectangle. but the code just give the region of the left corner part.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: `Region` isn't a valid command. Just do, eg: `u1 = RegionUnion[d1, d2, d3, d4]`, and the `RegionPlot[u1]`. Also, probably don't want to be using capital `D` as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks. That means Region command is not a command to define a region, and we don't need to define something as region before apply region related commands. Is it right?

Comment: Ah, apparently `Region` _is_ a command. Introduced in v.11, presumably. Sorry, my bad. But yeah, not a command to define a region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) when you want to view the region. The following does what you want:

```
u1 = RegionUnion[d1, d2, d3, d4];
u2 = Rectangle[{0,0}, {2,2}];
Region @ RegionDifference[u2, u1]
```

[image]